# Why isn't VirusTotal detecting a zip file that contains malware?

Tags: malware

**Summary**

1. On [www.virustotal.com](http://www.virustotal.com), I have just used its "Scan a URL" feature to see if it
detects malware within zip files.

I found a test zip file containing malware (I believe), at

https://github.com/ActorExpose/source-code-apk-malware

The actual file containing the malware is

https://github.com/ActorExpose/source-code-apk-malware/archive/refs/heads/main.zip

2. So I pasted the above zip file URL into VirusTotal's url box, and hit ENTER.
But to my surprise, the result showed "0/88: No security vendors flagged this
URL as malicious".

3. **So my questions are:**

a) Does this mean that VirusTotal is not detecting the malware?
b) If not, why not?
c) Or have I chosen a zip file on github that doesn't actually contain malware?
d) If the latter is the case, where can I find a zip file that does contain
malware, so that I can test it on VirusTotal?
e) Is there a reputable site that has such a sample zip file?

**Full Details**

4. Initially, I ran the malware checker [www.virustotal.com](http://www.virustotal.com) on the Firefox
extension visited-color-picker. This is because I was considering downloading
the extension, but Firefox point out that they don't maintain security checks on
it. The extension changes the colour of visited links to the colour of your
choice.

You see, Firefox's own visited links color selector doesn't work satisfactorily
(yes I HAVE selected "Always" in Firefox's Preferences...Colors).

5. The extension visited-color-picker can be downloaded from

https://github.com/william-billaud/visited-color-picker

And the file to download is

https://github.com/william-billaud/visited-color-picker/archive/refs/heads/master.zip

6. So I used VirusTotal's "Scan a URL" feature, and pasted the above URL address
of the zip file into the box.

The result showed "0/88: No security vendors flagged this URL as malicious".

7. But I decided to check if [www.virustotal.com](http://www.virustotal.com) really does detect malware. So I
found what I believe is a zip file containing malware, at

https://github.com/ActorExpose/source-code-apk-malware

The rest is explained in the "Summary" at the start.

Comment: I fail to see how this is related to Unix/Linux . Even if it's checking something running on Android thus Linux, what is checking is an arbitrary web site, not a local tool.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not Unix or Linux related.

Comment: I'm sorry that this isn't the right place to post my question. I'm a Linux user
and have posted several previous questions to this site (the message incorrectly
says I'm a new contributor).

It never occurred to me that my question might not sound Linux related.

But we're all here on this planet to help each other aren't we. Isn't it much
nicer to kindly point someone in the right direction, instead of being
judgemental, or clamouring to close the question. ...

Comment: ... A kind word like the following would have helped a lot:
"I'm so sorry, but questions have to be specific to Unix/Linux. A better place
to submit your question would be www.this.site."

Can I apologise for mentioning it, but the code of conduct for all of us fine
people (https://unix.stackexchange.com/conduct) says that the unix.stackexchange
community "is rooted in kindness, collaboration, and mutual respect". And "If
you’re here to help others, be patient and welcoming".

Answer (score 1):

The repository's description says "source code of apk malware in zip files". VirusTotal scans for actual threats. "Threat" as in "this executable program is malicious". As far as I can tell, there are no executable binaries provided in the given repository.